# How to trim an output of a foreach over an array

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

Ive got an array of Wordpress-Categories. What I want, is to output their names, seperated with a comma. - like this:

`category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, ...`

I tried this foreach loop:

```
foreach ($category as $cat){
  $catList = $cat->name.', ';
  echo $catList ;
}
```

But the output looks like this: `category1, category2, category3,`

As you can see, there is a comma at the end, which I dont want.

How would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way, just off the top of my head:

```
$firstitem=1;
foreach ($category as $cat) {
    if ($firstitem == 1) {
        $firstitem = 0;
    } else {
        $catList .= ', ';
    }
    $catList .= $cat->name;
}
echo $catList ;
```

Of course, you could just echo the comma and name values without saving them. I did it this way in case you wanted to do something else with the catList string.

Answer (score 1):

One and simple [built-in function](http://php.net/manual/it/function.implode.php):

```
$catList = implode(", ", $category);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it correct, but you don't need to use it inside the loop,
just one time after the for loop ends

```
for(.....){

}
$catlist= rtrim($catlist, ', ');
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would look like this: (untested)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
  echo $category[$i]->name;
  echo ($i - 1 < count($category)) ? ', ' : '';
}
```

This will only output the commas after all elements except when `$i - 1` is less than the length of the category array. That means after all elements, except the last one.